# How to implement a global UI state for isLoading in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, state

I'm working on an Android Jetpack Compose project and I want to implement a global UI state to handle loading indicators across different screens. What's the recommended approach to create a global `isLoading` state in Jetpack Compose? I've heard about using `ViewModels` and `MutableState`, but I'm looking for a comprehensive example or guidance on how to set up and manage this global UI state efficiently. Any help or code samples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think setting up Loading UI state globally is not a good practice. you could have ```Sealed Class``` Of UI State which you can use in every screen with different parameter and on Common parameter for loading.